# deeplink does not open instargam app

Tags: android, instagram

I set up webviewClient to open all instagram links inside it except link provided by button "open in app"

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

          @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.e("mcheck", "" + url);
            if (!url.contains("com.instagram.android")) {
              view.loadUrl(url);
              return false;
            } else {
              Log.e("mcheck", "want to open outside" + url);

              return true;
            }
          }
        });
```

However, when i click that button following link does not open an android application, either google play

```
intent://instagram.com/_u/ververa/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end
```

Why is it so?